# Magento 2 : Not able to get the frequently bought product collection in frontend same as related products

Tags: magento2, module

Right now I'm building a custom module and I am not able to get the frequently bought product collection in the frontend from the backend.
if anyone has any idea about it then please advise!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this block to get the related products please use this code in your module layout files.

```
 <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" name="catalog.product.related" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">related</argument>
                </arguments>
</block>
```